# UIViewController in UIPopoverController always reports as being in Portrait mode

Tags: ios, ipad

I've got a view controller in a UIPopoverController. I want to adjust the ui based on whether or not it is in portrait orientation.

No matter what orientation my iPad is in (physical device), self.interfaceOrientation always reports Portrait. I'm logging it in -viewWillAppear: and it's always Portrait.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

to recognize statusBar oriantation.

Comment: You have a mistake in your post. The `statusBarOrientation` is of type  `UIInterfaceOrientation`, not `UIDeviceOrientation`.

Comment: Seems to work just fine after the edit: UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)

Answer (score 2):

A view controller in a popover is always in portrait. The popover's orientation is always portrait no matter which way the device is held.

If you wish to do something different in the view controller based on the device's orientation, look at the `UIApplication statusBarOrientation`.

Think of the popover as following gravity. It always points down.